# best way to transfer facebook response from one js file to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, google-maps

I want to know the best way to transfer a response object, that I get after validating a user from Facebook, from one javascript file to another.

I want to do this as I want to get the friends location of the users, which is in my `fb.js` file, and transfer it to `gmap.js` file where I will be creating a map and adding the markers.

I am using nodeJS as my server and I use `module.exports` to transfer data from one file to another. But in this case I don't really know how I should export it. Any way to transfer the response is good for me

```
function login()
{   
  FB.login(function (response) 
  {
      if(response.authResponse)
      {  
          console.log("login successful");
      }
  },{scope: "public_profile,email,user_tagged_places,user_friends" });
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would need to "transfer" an object to another file?  Do you have you want to access Functions that are in another file?  I would reccommend using require.js and just pull the other js files in and you'll have access to all the functions in all the files ... not to "transfer" the object to another file

Comment: I dont want to have access to my facebook functions. However, the response they give me, that contains names and locations. This is needed by my google map to add the markers. So you are saying using require.js will get the response that facebook returns to my google map js file? Can you please tell me how to use the require.js to transfer specifically the response. I am adding the response I get above. @ScottSelby.

Comment: You don't "transfer" things. You write code that calls FB API, gets data and tells GMaps to do something via their API. That's called programming. Their JavaScript files don't know what to do with your objects unless you create a program.

Answer (score 0):

since it seems that you are not listening to suggestions that were provided by myself and other comments here is code that will "transfer" your object to another javscript file.

Which again , is absolutely not the correct approach.  What your problem is , as I understand it is this:  you make an ajax call to Facebook (or wherever) and get a response back.  You now need to take this response object and pass it to code in another javascript file which is not accessible at this point.  The correct thing to do here is to make that jaascript file - either the entire thing or just the functions that you need accessible.  In Object-Oriented languages you would change the privicy level to make these function `public`, you obviously can't do that here, so you have a few options:

-Do something like this with require.js

```
// this will be at the top of your javascript file.
// what this is doing is pulling your fb.js file into this file
// and making ever function in fb.js accessible here
define(['javascript/myPathToJsFiles/gmap'],
  function( gmap) {
  // everything in this js file will go in here
  // all of this code has fb and gmap available to use with 'fb' and 'gmap'


  function login()
  {   
      FB.login(function (response) 
      {
          if(response.authResponse)
          {  
              var respFromGmap =  gmap.myFunctionNameInGmapFile(response);
              console.log("login successful");
          }
      },{scope: "public_profile,email,user_tagged_places,user_friends" });
    }
..
..
```

ok, here is code if you just want to ignore everything and literally transfer an object to another file and keep them completely separate from each other.  M y example is going to call `FB.Login` and then store the response to a global variable , then the global variable can be accessed anywhere.

```
FB.login(function (response) 
{
    if(response.authResponse)
    {  
        // if this code is running on a browser replace  GLOBAL with window

        // I can't stress enough how bad of an idea this is , but anyway if
        // you must  use a global var then make sure it has a really long 
        // and really descriptive name to prevent getting mixed up and 
        // overridden
        GLOBAL.facebookLoginResponseObject = response;
    }
}
```

now in gmap.js or ANY other js file that is off on it's own being lonely and antisocial and has no access to that code with `FB.login`

```
fuction useLoginObject(){
   // the "|| {}" just makes sure you won't throw an exception , it will return 
   // an empty object if nothing was found in the global 
   var fbLoginObject = GLOBAL.facebookLoginResponseObject || {};
}
```

Comment: The suggestions were more like a beat down for me. Please excuse my "transfer" terminology as I am very new to programming and it was my bad @ScottSelby. 
Thank you very much for the much needed answers though. I tried all of the steaps you wrote. Putting all my facebook and google maps function in one file worked for me.

Comment: One more thing I would like to ask @ScottSelby, 
I can use require and other modules in my app.js and routes.js files.
However, I cannot use require.js, module.exports or GLOBAL keyword in my JS files which are in my public folder, ie client side folder.
 Every time start my server and load the page which is linked to my  client side JS files, I get reference error eg, require not defined. Is this because these JS files are running on the client side?